# How to play an mp3 in html that's been uploaded to python?

Tags: python, html, django

I just started on python / django and I was wondering if there was any way to play an uploaded mp3? I'm able to open an uploaded docx or txt file but with mp3s and playing them, I'm getting "Not Found: /list/03 The Forgotten.mp3", with 03 The Forgotten.mp3 being some random song I've uploaded.

Here's my views.py

```
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from docx import Document
from polls.models import Document
from polls.forms import DocumentForm
from django.http import HttpResponse



import docx2txt
def list(request):
    # Handle file upload
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc =  request.FILES['docfile']
            #newdoc.save()
            try:
                name = newdoc.name
                if name.endswith("docx"):
                    text = docx2txt.process(newdoc)
                    context["uploadedFile"] = text
                elif name.endswith("txt"):
                    context["uploadedFile"] = newdoc.read()
                elif name.endswith("mp3"):
                    context["sound"] = newdoc
                    context["uploadedFile"] = "enjoy!"


            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            #return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls.views.list'))
            #context["uploadedFile"] = newdoc.read()
            except:
                context["uploadedFile"] = "not a word doc"





            return render_to_response('fileUploadPage.html', context)
    else:
        form = DocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form

    # Load documents for the list page
    documents = Document.objects.all()


    # Render list page with the documents and the form
    return render_to_response(
        'polls/list.html',
        {'documents': documents, 'form': form},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

and my html page, list.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Minimal Django File Upload Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- List of uploaded documents -->
    {% if documents %}
        <ul>
        {% for document in documents %}
            <li><a href="{{ document.docfile.url }}">{{ document.docfile.name }}</a></li>

        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>No documents.</p>
    {% endif %}

        <!-- Upload form. Note enctype attribute! -->
        <form action="{% url 'list' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>
            <p>{{ form.docfile.label_tag }} {{ form.docfile.help_text }}</p>
            <p>
                {{ form.docfile.errors }}
                {{ form.docfile }}
            </p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and finally my fileUploadPage.html

```
<div id="uploaded">
    {{ uploadedFile }}

    <audio id="Player" autoplay>
     <source src= "{{sound}}" />
    </audio>
</div>
```

my fileUploadPage is outside my apps folder inside template (templates/myapp/) it is instead just in templates (templates/)

Comment: Have you tried placing the file in a location that the web server can provide to the client?

Comment: I have not. I will go learn how to save things and find out.